# Edit Linked Library add-on for 2.8

Tags: add-on

Is it possible with Blender 2.8 to go directly to the source file of the linked object, from the destination file, as did the "Edit Linked Library" addon that works in 2.79?
If no, will this addon be updated soon?

Comment: *Edit Linked Library* is shipped with Blender 2.8x, you just need to enable it...

Answer (score 1):

You can enable *Edit Linked Library* in the preferences (*Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*).

[image]